# Get Content-Type of requested url in php

Tags: php, header, content-type

Using php how would I be able to define the variable `$type` into the `content-type` of http://www.example.com

For example: `$type` defined as `"text/html"`

So far this is what i am working with:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
print_r(get_headers($url));
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
?>
```

The code may be changed as much as needed

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried:

```
$type = get_headers($url, 1)["Content-Type"];
```

As noted in comments by @Michael, this syntax won't work without a very current version of PHP.

Have you also tried:

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$type = $headers["Content-Type"];
```

?

Comment: Note that this syntax `()[]` is only valid in PHP 5.4. Earlier versions require you save the array to a variable, then retrieve the key.

Comment: My php is 5.3.13, is the second code snippet supposed to work on versions below 5.4 because i'm getting _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE_

Comment: Second snippet worked great for me on PHP 5.4.36.  +1

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes get_header return wrong values becouse it read http headers, but not file.
It should be better use finfo:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$type = $finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear on what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to get the request content type that was sent by the browser to your script, you can do this:

```
<?php 
// Collect all headers
$headers = [];
foreach(getallheaders() as $name => $header){
    $headers[strtolower($name)] = $header;
}

// Get the content type header
$contentType = $headers['content-type'];
?>
```