# How can I tell the filetype of images without extension? How do they work?

Tags: php

I am dealing with images on the web that come without a file extension, like this:

```
https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52a74d9ae4b0253945d2aee9/t/52ed63b1e4b04368c021b921/1463088116168/?format=500w
```

Images like these can be found, e.g., on websites made with squarespace, like this demo: https://bedford-demo.squarespace.com/

I'm trying to download these images and store them on my server, using PHP. But how can I find out the actual URL of those images? How does this work? And how can I tell the filetype of this image? What is this sorcery?

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

To find out the `Content-Type` returned for any URL, look at this answer:
[Get Content-Type of requested URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12023961/1242470)

---

**Why you need the `Content-Type`:**

Just like how not every webpage on the internet has an URL that ends with `.html`, images are not required to have an "extension" in their URL either.

What determines whether the browser will treat the data retrieved from the URL as an image is the **`Content-Type` header in the HTTP response**.

The URL you posted returns the following HTTP headers:

[image]

For HTML documents the `Content-Type` is `text/html`. You can inspect the headers as you browse by opening the *Network* tab of the developer console in your browser. Look for the "response headers".

Answer (score 2):

You can get the mime type of the file with [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52a74d9ae4b0253945d2aee9".
            "/t/52ed63b1e4b04368c021b921/1463088116168/?format=500w");
print_r($size["mime"]);
?>
```

Prints:

```
image/jpeg
```