# Check if the entered URL is for image or not

Tags: php, regex

```
function URL ($url, $type)
{
    $regex = '_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS';
    if($type == 'image') {
        $regex .= "";
    }

    if (preg_match($regex, $url)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With my function here i'm trying to validate a URL, And if i set the type to `image` to check if all the URL is an image or now, Then return `true` or `false`,

What i want to know is What do i add to my `regex` to check if the URL is for image or not, Then to return `true` in case the type is `image` and all the `regex` is matched to `image`

Comment: I don't think you can make this work. What happens with sites that don't show the resources' extension? I think imgur for example does that. What you need to do is something like sending a HEAD request and checking the `Content-Type`
.

Comment: I won't read a 500 character regex, but since you included `$` as the end of your regex, you won't be able to add additional matching characters (you can, but it will not ever match anything).

Comment: @ishegg doesn't imgur provide a direct url to the image itself?

Comment: As what @ishegg said, there is no reliable way to determine a specific URI will return an image, because you cannot determine the mime-type/content-type based on the URI alone. Your best way is actually to [attempt to load the image using `get_headers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023950/get-content-type-of-requested-url-in-php), and see what you get in return.

Comment: You can't tell the file type from a URL. You need to request it and check the content-type. HEAD request should be enough. There are picture hosting sites that have links ending in .jpg but they give you a website with ads and the picture.

Comment: @Terry i'm aiming to check a direct url like this one `https://i.imgur.com/**********.jpg`

Comment: Then just check if the URL ends with any of the known image extensions, e.g. `.*\.(jpe?g|png|tiff?|gif|bmp|svg|webp)$`. However be warned that this is **not an exhaustive check**: URLs without extensions might return an image, and URLs with an image might return a webpage. It is the server that determines what content to serve, and you cannot determine that just by eyeballing the URL alone.

Comment: @Terry So instead of checking the `.ext` it is better to check the `HEAD` request?

Comment: Yes, because you can serve extension-less URLs.

Comment: @Terry Does using `HEAD` request to check the type uses bandwidth equal to downloading all the image?